# GoLang TCP Connection - Remote Network is down check

Tags: go, tcp

I am creating a GoLang application and clients are android phones. I am able to handle connections. If user closes the android application connection is dropped with `EOF`

My problem is, if client just turn off wifi network connection is still alive.

Here is my code

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting server...")
    connection, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":4406")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer connection.Close()
    manager := ClientManager{
        clients:    make(map[*Client]bool),
        broadcast:  make(chan []byte),
        register:   make(chan *Client),
    }

    go manager.start()
    for {
        connection, _ := connection.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        client := &Client{socket: connection, data: make(chan []byte), uuid: connection.RemoteAddr().String()}

        manager.register <- client
        go manager.receive(client)
        go handleConnection(client)
    }

}
```

Handeling connections

```
func handleConnection(client *Client) {

    conn := client.socket
    defer conn.Close()
    notify := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        for {
            n, err := conn.Read(buf)
            if err != nil {
                notify <- err
                return
            }
            if n > 0 {
                fmt.Println("unexpected data: %s", buf[:n])
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case err := <-notify:
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("connection dropped message", err)
                return
            }
        case <-time.After(time.Second * 1):
            fmt.Println("timeout 1, still alive")
        }
    }
}
```

When remote wifi is off (cable removed) I want to disconnect the user. I tried to read a byte and every second and it is reading it. I sent a byte and it is sent as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do in handleConnection? If there is any error other than EOF, it will loop indefinitely, because the goroutine will exit, but handleConnection will not. To read with a timeout, simply call [SetReadDeadline](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn). But I also don't understand how you go from "there is a read timeout" to "the connection is still alive". Sounds backward to me.

Comment: @peter I have updated that `EOF` check. I will check with SetReadDeadline you mentioned. I am new to TCP and while testing I noticed that there are many open TCP connections for which i came to know that if remote network is closed without able to send close message to TCP server, that connection keeps open for days. My android app do communicate with 1 min interval

Comment: Then some kind of idle timeout is more applicable than a read timeout. For instance, record the last time a connection was active and periodically go through all of them and close those that were active more than N seconds ago.

Comment: Timer logic worked, need to improvise the logic bit more.. but thanks

Comment: You can implement a _heartbeat_ mechanism which is widely used to determine alive connections.